# Is it possible to pull a table's create syntax via mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to pull a table's create syntax via mysql and php. Is it possible?

I need it for a file that creates table_x automatically every 10 days. Since I update the site constantly and create new fields I'd like the file to be dynamic and use the previous table (instead of me updating it manually each time).

Comment: What happens if you need to recreate your database from scratch?

Comment: I understand your point, but I don't see why I would need to do that. I'd be able to copy the syntax from a backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can - use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;
```

Actually if you want to 'reset' your database I would use TRUNCATE instead

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

Comment: Thanks, had no idea it was that simple.

Comment: :-) cool when it does what you want - also checkout TRUNCATE TABLE (added to my answer) it may be more of what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_x;
```

...will output one record with the CREATE syntax. Is that what you're looking for?